# Transfer owner all documents to Administrator account using API (Google Drive)

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using Google Apps for Work. I try to take ownership for ALL file in user's Google Drive to Administrator account using APIs, via the latest Drive API http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1247799

With super admin permission, I can't use `setowner`to take ownership (action not allowed)

Answer (score 1):

Only the owner of the file can grant access or ownership to other users. Even as admin, you won't have that kind of permission.

In order to accomplish this, as an admin you can "impersonate" the user and then perform actions on user's behalf.

This is done using [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) with [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation) permissions.

After doing this, you can call the API's as the user and give the admin(yourself) owner permissions of the user's files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: May you please update the second url? It's outdated and I would like to know how to do what you are explaining :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  this is the correct url: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account

Comment: Not your bad, just outdated Link. Thanks a lot!